# Пропал перевод режимов просмотра редакции

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, история-правок

При просмотре чьей-либо правки можно просматривать правку в различных режимах.
Насколько я помню, раньше эти режимы были переведены как "Внутристрочный", "В две колонки" и "В две колонки с разметкой Markdown".

---

Сейчас перевод этих кнопок отсутствует

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переводы добавлены и уже доступны на сайте:

> [image: Режим отображения изменений]